# Domain name to IPv6 address in Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, ip-address, ipv6, gethostbyname

I have the following Perl code to translate domain name to IP address. It works fine in IPv4.

```
$host = "example.com";
$ip_address = join('.', unpack('C4',(gethostbyname($host))[4]));
```

However, it does not work if it is an IPv6 only domain name such as "ipv6.google.com".

How can I get one line of code (prefer CORE library) to get IPv6 IP address?

```
$host = "ipv6.google.com";
$ip_address = ???
```

Comment: what version of perl?

Comment: I'm looking at Perl 5.10 and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 5.14 and above, you can use the core [`Socket`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html):

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Socket ();

# protocol and family are optional and restrict the addresses returned
my ( $err, @addrs ) = Socket::getaddrinfo( $ARGV[0], 0, { 'protocol' => Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, 'family' => Socket::AF_INET6 } );
die $err if $err;

for my $addr (@addrs) {
    my ( $err, $host ) = Socket::getnameinfo( $addr->{addr}, Socket::NI_NUMERICHOST );
    if ($err) { warn $err; next }
    say $host;
}
```

For earlier perls, the same functions are available from [`Socket::GetAddrInfo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Socket%3a%3aGetAddrInfo) on CPAN.

Comment: Socket is dual-lived. Is there any reason to install Socket::GetAddrInfo instead of upgrading Socket?

Comment: I'm getting the following error using Perl 5.16 Windows.

ai_family not supported at a.pl line 7.

Comment: @Micheal C., Replicated and solved by upgrading Socket (`cpan Socket`)

Comment: @ikegami I have the latest Socket 2.014 but same error.

Comment: @MichaelC. You might just be on a build of Windows or Perl that doesn't support IPv6 directly. This is the correct method to perform 'v6 resolutions, so if it doesn't work then something somewhere in the chain is missing.

Comment: @ysth: Any reason you performed an empty import from `Socket` then called all the functions and constants fully-qualified? Normally it'd be neater to import the required symbols.

Comment: I find it neater to indicate at each call which package something is in, especially constants.

Answer (score -1):

[`Net::DNS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aDNS) can also help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                  
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::DNS;

my $res   = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;
my $query = $res->query("ipv6.google.com", "AAAA")
    or die "query failed: ", $res->errorstring;

foreach my $rr (grep { $_->type eq 'AAAA' } $query->answer) {
    print $rr->address, "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
2607:f8b0:4010:801:0:0:0:1005
```

Comment: Note that accessing DNS directly instead of using the system's name lookup interface (`getaddrinfo`) will hide host file entries.

Comment: Anyway to avoid the use Net::DNS ?

Comment: Downvoting because: You shouldn't ever be concerned directly with DNS unless that is your entire function - to perform some sort of DNS-specific lookup. In 99.9% of cases, programs aren't. Instead they just want to use the system resolver, `getaddrinfo`. See other answer.